# Determine target's Build Configuration type from static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I get the build configuration type from a static library (debug or release)?
Normally we use `#ifdef DEBUG` but in this case it will not work, because this check is compile time and our static library is already compiled.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow - are you trying to determine how the static library was built? What config type the app using the library is being run under?

Comment: No. I want to know what config type the app using itself

Comment: I don't think you're able to do that, as it would not be set at the time your code is compiled. I'm curious if there is another way to solve your initial problem - maybe have 2 versions of the library and link the appropriate one in the app?

Comment: My goal is to determine the build type of the app and send it to the server...

Comment: Ok, so couldn't you make a method that takes it in as a parameter to the library, then use #ifdef etc. to set that from the app? I'm assuming are writing both pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if the app was compiled in debug or production (AdHoc equals production), you can use the following method, which can be called within the static library:

```
+ (BOOL)isDevelopmentBuild
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return YES;
#else
    BOOL isDevelopment = NO;

    // There is no provisioning profile in AppStore Apps.
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"embedded" ofType:@"mobileprovision"]];
    if (data) {
        const char *bytes = [data bytes];
        NSMutableString *profile = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:data.length];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            [profile appendFormat:@"%c", bytes[i]];
        }
        // Look for debug value, if detected we're in a development build.
        NSString *cleared = [[profile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        isDevelopment = ([cleared rangeOfString:@"<key>get-task-allow</key><true/>"].length > 0);
    } 

    return isDevelopment;
#endif
}
```

**Notice it will return YES if the app is in development mode.**

Comment: Well, your answer is useful, but actually I want to know the build type of the app (debug or release), and doesn't matter is it running on a simulator or on a device. See screenshot:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/atvlm9.jpg

Comment: The simulator is just a specific check in order to avoids unnecessary code. It returns Yes if it's in development mode, otherwise No. Please try it in your code and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Just to clarify - if you check this method one real device in development mode, it will return YES.

Comment: Seems it works on the device. But what about simulator?

Comment: Simulator will always return YES cause you can't really install a release version on it (as far as I know).

Comment: Actually if you switch to Release mode from "Edit Scheme", it will release version :))

Comment: So just remove the if statement and it will work as expected on simulator also

Comment: On the simulator the data is nil, because the is no mobileprovision in the simulator

Comment: I'll check it soon, but if it's ok to ask, why to "care" about simulator?

Comment: One more question. Will this app be rejected from app submission by AppStore? Because I read somewhere that we can't read content of embedded.mobileprovision file.

Comment: No it won't - I have many iOS apps with this method in the AppStore.

Comment: Ok. Thank you ver much. And please, if you find a way for simulator, let me know